# Override ActionMailer's mail to address in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my development environment, I use a copy of the production database when testing locally. For reasons both for testing and simply for protection against sending out test/dev emails to real users, what's the best way to override the mail-to address when in development mode?

I know I can write logic in each mailer, but I have several and it would be nice to put it all in once place. Can I override the `mail()` method somehow to make the `:to` parameter always point at an email address I specify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best option is to use a service like mailtrap.io: http://mailtrap.io or mailcatcher gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/mailcatcher

Comment: mailcatcher is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

I use an [ActionMailer interceptor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#label-Observing+and+Intercepting+Mails) so all mails sent while in development or test environments are sent to the same address. Like this:

```rb
# config/initializers/override_mail_recipient.rb
if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
  class OverrideMailRecipient
    def self.delivering_email(mail)
      mail.to = 'to@example.com'
    end
    ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(OverrideMailRecipient)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is pretty neat actually. Thanks for the snippet!

Answer (score 3):

What I like to do is configure action mailer in the development environment to use [mailtrap](http://www.rubyinside.com/mailtrap-dummy-ruby-smtp-server-ideal-for-testing-actionmailer-629.html).

Answer (score 1):

You [could do](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) a default of

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :to=> "to@example.com"
end
```

And then make the address an option in the methods. That way it would default to the `:to` you set.  Another idea I had was a bit more:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  attr_accessor :email_address

  def initialize
    if RAILS_ENV == "development"
      @email_address = "to@example.com"
    end
  end
end
```

That would require you to set a new address in your code but it would be overwritten each time in Development.