# Override ActionMailer subject in staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I would like all the emails sent from our staging server to have the phrase "[STAGING] " prefaced in the subject. Is there an elegant way to do this in Rails 3.2 using ActionMailer?

Comment: Make sure you use your own email recipients database, so you don't accidentally spam your customers. Thats in general not appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's an elegant solution I found using [ActionMailer Interceptor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#label-Observing+and+Intercepting+Mails) based on [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10870805/307438).

```
# config/initializers/change_staging_email_subject.rb
if Rails.env.staging?
  class ChangeStagingEmailSubject
    def self.delivering_email(mail)
      mail.subject = "[STAGING] " + mail.subject
    end
  end
  ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(ChangeStagingEmailSubject)
end
```

Comment: `mail.subject.prepend("[#{Rails.env}]")` slightly more "change friendly"

Answer (score 5):

This works for Rails 4.x

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  after_action do
    mail.subject.prepend('[Staging] ') if Rails.env.staging?
  end

  (...)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, inheritance is about as elegant as it gets.

```
class OurNewMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => 'no-reply@example.com',
          :return_path => 'system@example.com'

  def subjectify subject
    return "[STAGING] #{subject}" if Rails.env.staging?
    subject
  end
end
```

Then you can inherit from each of your mailers.

```
# modified from the rails guides
class Notifier < OurNewMailer

  def welcome(recipient)
    @account = recipient
    mail(:to => recipient.email_address_with_name, :subject => subjectify("Important Message"))
  end
end
```

I don't think this is as clean as what you were hopeing for, but this will dry it up a bit.

Comment: In case you're interested, I think I found a better solution. Have a look at the answer I provided.